# Alert not displaying when pressing the back button on the device within Modal

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm facing a challenge where I want to display an **`Alert`** when users press the back button on the device within a Modal in my React Native application. The desired behavior is to show an **`Alert`** with the message "You have turned off the modal using the device's back button", and then close the modal. Below is my source code:

```
import {
  View,
  Text,
  Modal,
  StyleSheet,
  Button,
  Alert,
  BackHandler,
  TouchableOpacity,
} from 'react-native';
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';

const Lab3_3 = () => {
   const [modalVisible, setModalVisible] = useState(false);
   useEffect(() => {
     const handleBackPress = () => {
       if (modalVisible) {
         Alert.alert(
           'Alert',
           'You have turned off the modal using the devices back button',
           [{text: 'OK', onPress: () => setModalVisible(false)}],
         );
         return true; 
       }
       return false; 
     };

     const backHandler = BackHandler.addEventListener(
       'hardwareBackPress',
       handleBackPress,
     );

     return () => {
       backHandler.remove();
     };
   }, [modalVisible]);



  return (
    <View>
      <Modal
        animationType="slide"
        transparent={true}
        visible={modalVisible}
        onRequestClose={() => setModalVisible(false)}>
        <View style={styles.centeredView}>
          <View style={styles.modalView}>
            <Text>Hello world!</Text>
            <Button title="Close Modal" onPress={() => setModalVisible(false)} />
          </View>
        </View>
      </Modal>

      <TouchableOpacity
        style={styles.customButton}
        onPress={() => setModalVisible(true)}>
        <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Open Modal</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  customButton: {
    width: '100%',
    height: '100%',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  buttonText: {
    color: 'white',
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    padding: 10,
    backgroundColor: 'green',
    borderRadius: 5,
  },
  centeredView: {
    width: '100%',
    height: '100%',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    marginTop: 22,
  },
  modalView: {
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    borderRadius: 20,
    padding: 20,
    alignItems: 'center',
    elevation: 5,
  },
});

export default Lab3_3;
```

I'm looking for suggestions or solutions to ensure that the desired Alert behavior is achieved. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per React Native documents ["BackHandler events will not be emitted as long as the modal is open"](https://reactnative.dev/docs/modal#onrequestclose)

You need to put your logic inside onRequestClose callBack.

Something like:

```
<Modal
      // ... otherProps
      onRequestClose={() =>
        Alert.alert(
          "Alert",
          "You have turned off the modal using the devices back button",
          [{ text: "OK", onPress: () => setModalVisible(false) }]
        )
      }
    />

// ...rest
```

Alternatively:

```
<Modal
      // ... otherProps
      onRequestClose={() =>
        Platform.OS === "android"
          ? Alert.alert(
              "Alert",
              "You have turned off the modal using the devices back button",
              [{ text: "OK", onPress: () => setModalVisible(false) }]
            )
          : setModalVisible(false)
      }
    />

// ...rest
```

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the [docs for onRequestClose](https://reactnative.dev/docs/0.72/modal#onrequestclose)

> Because of this required prop, be aware that BackHandler events will not be emitted as long as the modal is open.

And in the [Backhandler docs](https://reactnative.dev/docs/0.73/backhandler)

> Warning for modal users: If your app shows an opened Modal, BackHandler will not publish any events (see Modal docs).

So you're event listener is not getting triggered. But this is the default rule. You'd have to use something other than a modal, (i.e. a view that has animations, etc.) for your desired behavior.

Sorry!